# Only the first column row printing out for RDLC mailing label

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I have used some examples on how to create mailing label sheet using RDLC.  I have data being displayed but I only have the first column of the first row being displayed in the report viewer.  I have a total of 6 records I'm dealing with.  I thought I would get 2 rows of data to print out.  Did anybody else have this same issue and how did you resolve it?

Thank you

Comment: This is a known issue with the `ReportViewer` display, but will render correctly when you **Print** or **Export** your report.  For more info on using columns see [Printing label sheets through RDLC](https://nav-magno.be/2013/09/printing-label-sheets-through-rdlc/) or [How to use ReportViewer to create addressing label](https://www.learningpenguin.net/myblog/2011/02/03/how-to-use-reportviewer-to-create-addressing-label/)